# isolated groups in a graph

Tags: python, networkx

I want to write a piece of code to detect the groups of nodes inside a graph. As an example see the image attached. There I plot a graph with 3 groups of nodes. the outcome of the algorithm should be {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4 ,6 ,7}, {5, 8}.

My intuition is to run a DFS algorithm for each node marking the found nodes (those it can reach), if I do this for the node 0, it'll mark nodes 1 and 2. If I run it then for node 1 it'll find none since all the nodes in its group are already marked. Each group of discovered nodes per each node DFS will be a group. In the end I'll keep the not null groups.

My question is: can I find the groups using some sort of clustering algorithm?

The code is for a test graph:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()

g.add_edge(0, 1)
g.add_edge(1, 2)

g.add_edge(6, 7)
g.add_edge(4, 7)
g.add_edge(3, 4)

g.add_edge(5, 8)


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
nx.draw(g)

plt.show()
```

[image: Graph plot]

EDIT

As commented below the answer is:

```
from networkx import connected_components
connected_components(g)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [connected_components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components) function of networkx what you are looking for? From a graph, it returns a generator of lists, each generated item being a list of connected nodes.

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This answer is based on an old version of networkx.  `connected_components` no longer returns a list of lists.  It returns a generator.  If you try to use it like a list, things can go wrong.  Here is more recent documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components